# How to reset setTimeout variable using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to reset the timer value (i.e set to its initial value)
MY code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var timer;
   timer_clock();
    function timeout()
    {
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
            if(timer < 15)
            {
                timeout();
            }
            else
            {

               clearTimeout(timer);
               timer = null;
                //window.clearTimeout(timer);
                //  alert(timer);
                timeout_2();
            }
        },1);
    }

    function timeout_2()
    {
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
// this alert shows value from 16 ..but i want it to start from 0
            alert(timer);
            timeout_2();
        },10);
    }

    function timeout1()
    {
        //clearTimeout(timer);
        timeout();
    }
function timer_clock()
    {

        timeout1();

    }
});
```

Now the browser is giving alertbox value starting from 16 Even after cleartimeout is used.. I want function timeout_2 to shows values from zero  ... Please suggest some solution

Comment: `timer` is just a integer pointing to a specific timer to keep reference. You cannot 'reset' it to any specific value. You have to implement your own variable to count currently running timers. That's said i didn't get deeply in your logic regarding your posted code and i'm not sure what you are really expecting here

Comment: You need to change the logic of your code, because as @A.Wolff said `timer` is only a pointer. If you play with `setTimeout()` you can reset it with `clearTimeout("timer")` but the number sumatory needs to be handled by yourself.